# EclipseLink connection pooling configuration

Tags: java, eclipselink, connection-pooling, spring-data-jpa

I am currently implementing the data-layer for an EE application. I am using latest version of `JPA, EclipseLink and Spring`. The servlet container is `VMware vFabric tc` (Tomcat).

As the title mentioned, **how should I do the connection pooling part ?**

Most tutorials are using `Hibernate` with an external library like `DBCP` or `C3PO`, but `EclipseLink` tutorials use Springs `DriverManagerDataSource` that has no connection pooling.

Does `EclipseLink` have a production level connection pooling feature integrated ?

Do I need to set my `datasource` with `JNDI` to use `Tomcat's` connection pooling ?

Can someone provide guidelines or an example configuration for a similar scenario, please ?

Thank you.